# Find the number of $n$ satisfying GCD$(2n+1,60)=1$, for $n=0,1,2,...,59$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $m$ be a positive integer with $m \geq 5$. Let us consider the set $$A=\{n \>| \> \text{GCD}(2n+1,m)=1, \> n=0,1,2,...,(m-1)\}.$$ Then is there any formula for finding the cardinality of the set $A$?
I know that for the set $\{n \>| \> \text{GCD}(n+1,m)=1, \> n=0,1,2,...,(m-1)\}$ the cardinality is $\phi(m)$, Euler phi function.
Let us take $m=60$. Then we have to find the number of $n$ satisfying GCD$(2n+1,60)=1$, for $n=0,1,2,...,59$. I get it by calculating for each $n$, but I want any formula or clear method for this. Since for $m>100$ there may be massive problem in calculation for each $n$.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: $60=2*3*5$, so you can apply Chinese Remainder theorem where $2$ have an inverse $\pmod{3},\pmod{5}$. The answer is $2\phi(3)\phi(5)$.

Comment: The answer seems to be $\varphi(2m)$: [A062570](https://oeis.org/A062570).

Comment: @Sil: it *is* $\varphi(2m)$, see my solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I address the general question: what is the number of $n\in[0,m-1]$ such that $\gcd(2n+1,m)=1$?

There are two cases to distinguish, according to whether $m$ is odd or even.

If $m$ is odd, then the $m$ numbers $2\cdot 0+1,\dotsc,2\cdot(m-1)+1$ are pairwise incongruent modulo $m$; hence, exactly $\varphi(m)$ of them are co-prime with $m$.

If $m$ is even, then the numbers $2\cdot 0+1,\dotsc,2\cdot(m-1)+1$ represent every odd residue class modulo $m$ twice, and do not represent any even residue class modulo $m$. Since the numbers co-prime with $m$ fall into the odd residue classes modulo $m$, it follows that exactly $2\varphi(m)$ among $2\cdot 0+1,\dotsc,2\cdot(m-1)+1$ are co-prime with $m$.

The bottom line is: the number of those $n\in[0,m-1]$ with $\gcd(2n+1,m)=1$ is
$$ \begin{cases}
     \varphi(m)\ &\text{if $m$ is odd},\\
     2\varphi(m)\ &\text{if $m$ is even.}
   \end{cases} $$